# Confusing conceptual question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

An observer $A$ standing on the circumference of a disc rotating with an uniform angular velocity $\omega = 1$ units , and radius $r=1$ units observes a person $B$ at rest w.r.t ground.Given the $\angle \theta = 30^\circ $ as shown in the figure[image]
Find out the,

1. relative velocity of $A$ w.r.t $B$
2. relative velocity of $B$ w.r.t $A$

My approach , for the first part was that $|V_{A/B}|=rw=1$ units, for the second part i thought since $|V_{B/A}|=|V_{A/B}|=1$, but i found out that the answer to second part is wrong and this formula doesnt work for rotating frames,i also tried this solving with proper maths but i always end up to this conclusion only, maybe i am not hitting the right concept can anyone please help with correct maths, concept for the second part , also how can we write a general expression of $V_{B/A}$ varying with time, the expression i was deriving is as follows $\vec{V_{B/A}}=-(\cos{t}\hat{i}+\sin{t}\hat{j}) $, where centre of circle is the origin. i am really sorry for not typing my work but if users want my work i can share its photo :) .

Edit: All units are in SI system

Comment: It's best to declare which units you are using, and to avoid assigning values of either 0 or 1 to your variables.  0 and 1 have mathematical properties which tend to hide errors in your work.

Comment: You need to give the answer as a vector and do not overthink it. What is the velocity vector of point **A**? That is the velocity of _A_ w.r.t. _B_.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou yes that i know but i m interested to know the v of B wrt A also

Comment: iF $\vec{v}$ is velocity of _A_ w.r.t. _B_, then $-\vec{v}$ is the velocity of _B_ w.r.t. _A_. Why would there be any doubt about this?

Comment: Can you write what answer is actually given in your book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix a Cartesian co-ordinate system that is at rest w.r.t the ground and has origin at the centre of the circle. Let's call the co-ordinates of $A$ and $B$ in this co-ordinate system $\vec r_A(t)$ and $\vec r_B(t)$. At time $t=0$ we have

$\vec r_A(0) = (0, -1) \\ \vec r_B(0) = (\sqrt 3, -1)$

At a general time $t$, $\vec r_B(t)$ does not change so $\vec r_B(t) = (\sqrt 3, -1)$, but $A$ has moved around the circle by an angle $\omega t$, so $\vec r_A(t) = (\sin (\omega t), - \cos (\omega t))$.

At time $t$ $A$'s position with respect to $B$ is $\vec r_A(t) - \vec r_B(t)$, and $A$'s velocity with respect to $B$ is

$\displaystyle \frac d {dt} \left( \vec r_A(t) - \vec r_B(t) \right) = \vec v_A(t) - \vec v_B(t) = v_A(t)$

since $v_B(t) = 0$. Similarly, $B$'s position with respect to $A$ is $\vec r_B(t) - \vec r_A(t)$, and $B$'s velocity with respect to $A$ is

$\displaystyle \frac d {dt} \left( \vec r_B(t) - \vec r_A(t) \right) = \vec v_B(t) - \vec v_A(t) = - \vec v_A(t)$

Comment: Thanks but i also approached exactly as u and end up with the same resupt but as i mention the its not correct the magintude of relative of A wrt B ≠ relative of B wrt A ,but ur solution clearly follows v of A wrt B= v of B wrt A in magnitude

Comment: @AkshajBansal Then perhaps the question intends you to find the velocity of $B$ relative to $A$ in a rotating frame of reference in which $A$ is stationary. This is not made clear - the question is ambiguous.

Comment: the question is clear , and what u say is also clearly indicated That A is on rest wrt to the rotating disc ......

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is that rotating frames don't support the principle of Galilean Invariance. To simplify the issue, get rid of the rotating disk and just consider observers A and B standing motionless, one metre apart. If A chooses an inertial frame of reference ('motionless and irrotational compared to the distant stars), then she will conclude that B is 1 m distant and motionless. But now let B perversely choose a rotating frame with origin at his location and $\omega = 1 $ rad/s. B would claim that A is now rotating around him with velocity $\pi$ m/s. Another observer C could pick another rotating frame with a distant origin and claim that both A and B were moving faster than the speed of light.

That is why inertial rest frames are generally used in classical mechanics. Rotating frames are useful for solving specific problems, but not for kinematics in general. That A is standing on a spinning disk doesn't require him/her to choose a rotating frame of reference (or if they do - to chose it's origin at the axis of the disk).